# Trying to make Tomcat 7 work on a machine locally, with no network connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, localhost, tomcat

What I'm trying to do is run Tomcat on a machine, and to use it locally. The machine will not have a network connection, no network adapter.

When I try to navigate to localhost or 127.0.0.1 I just get a white page with no content.

I am using windows 7

C:\Users\airship>netstat |  findstr :8080

TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52118        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52119        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52120        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52121        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52122        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52123        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52118            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52119            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52120            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52121            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52122            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52123            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED

C:\Users\airship>

Answer (score 0):

You probably have Skype installed which automatically takes port 80 if there is no application already using it. Default port for Tomcat is 8080. A blank page when connecting to http://127.0.0.1 means that something is listening on it. You can check with `netstat -anb | more` (it should be listed on top). So you have two options:

1. Stop skype, stop Tomcat, change Tomcat to listen on port 80, start Tomcat, Start Skype
2. browse to http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: This is a brand new windows 7 install, no other applications installed. I have also tried configuring tomcat to use ports other than 80 and it doesn't work.

I'd like to add when I DO have a network connection everything works, it's when I DONT have a network connection that things stop working

Comment: Strange. I just downloaded Tomcat 8.0.32 unzipped it and started, put my laptop in airplane mode (I am connected just to a WiFi network) and it works. Would you be so kind and share the output of `netstat | findstr :<your port>` so we can see where Tomcat does listen on, and have you tried with different browsers? (I always check with Chrome, FF, IE, Opera when something is not working - to make sure it is not a browser issue). Could you also verify that ping to 127.0.0.1 and localhost is working when the network connection is not there.

Comment: I found that if I browse to tomcats built in web app it works fine! That means it just must be my webapp thats messing up for some reason?



C:\Users\airship>netstat |  findstr :8080
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52118        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52119        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52120        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52121        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52122        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:8080             EMS-Trunk:52123        ESTABLISHED
Continued...

Comment: continued

  TCP    [::1]:52118            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52119            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52120            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52121            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52122            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::1]:52123            EMS-Trunk:8080         ESTABLISHED


C:\Users\airship>

Comment: Seems so. You have many established connections on port 8080. All are on IPv6. So Tomcat is working. As you said it is working if you have a network connection you could try to uncomment the line `# 127.0.0.1       localhost` in `"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"`